# .NET library or asp.net application for Amazon S3

Tags: asp.net, amazon-s3

I want to have a web based admin to upload, delete files and folders in Amazon S3 on ASP.NET website. 
I am pretty sure something like this already exist, has anyone seen it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried this one? http://www.codeplex.com/ThreeSharp

Answer (score 3):

[LitS3](http://code.google.com/p/lits3/) works great

Answer (score 0):

[Cloudberry has some cool products, I love the backup besides the explorer.](http://www.cloudberrylab.com)